# Netlogo: two files that have same code: one works, the other marks error

Tags: netlogo

I have two netlogo files with this identical code:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10
  [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
    ask turtles [
    ifelse any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    [rt random 40 lt random 40]
    [fd 1]]
  tick
end
```

In this file works: [test 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjr3soljckd7nbd/test%201.nlogo?dl=0),
but not on this one: [test 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/340yetnx6tlg15p/test%202.nlogo?dl=0). It states

> TURTLES-ON expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY
> instead.

Why does this happen?
The error code is part of a larger model that states the same error, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is due to the difference in world-wrapping in your two files- in Test 1 you have world wrapping on:

[image]

Whereas you have it turned off in Test 2:

[image]

This means any turtle that reaches the edge of the world is querying a patch that does not exist- a patch outside of the world (`nobody`). You can either turn world wrapping on, or address the movement model by checking that movement is possible either with something like `can-move?` or by coding it manually. For example, you could change your `go` in `test 2` to

```
to go
    ask turtles [
    ifelse patch-ahead 1 = nobody or any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    [rt random 40 lt random 40]
    [fd 1]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Note that order matters in this case- you have to check for `nobody` before checking `any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1`

Comment: @JavierSandoval - Glad to help, happy coding!